# Sending email with attachment in Python

Tags: python, email

I have code sending email in Python:

```
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.utils import formatdate

SERVER_ADDR = 'smtp.gmail.com'

def sendMail(dir, fromAddr, toAddr, subject, text, files):
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['From'] = fromAddr
  msg['To'] = toAddr
  msg['Date'] = datetime.date.today()
  msg['Subject'] = subject

  msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

  for file in files:
    part = MIMEBase('application',"octet-stream")
    part.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read )
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename {}'.format(os.path.basename(file)))
    msg.attach(part)

  smtp = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER_ADDR,587)
  smtp.sendmail(fromAddr,toAddr,msg.as_string())
  smtp.close()
  return 0

def main(argv):
  files = [argv[1]]
  sendMail(myemail,myemail,"Zalacznik","Tekst maila bla bla bla.",
           files) # I replaced my email here
  return 0

if __name__=="__main__":
  sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I've got error:

```
TypeError: sendMail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'files'
```

What is wrong with my code?

[EDIT]:
Ok I've removed dir from signature, but I have another error:

```
TypeError: expected bytes, not builtin function or method
```

Error is in line `encoders.encode_base64(part)`.

Comment: Seems like you lack one argument.

Comment: Please provide the code where your `sendMail` function is being called.

Comment: Or the full traceback, at least. The error is *outside* the code you currently provide.

Comment: You are missing one argument. Your sendMail function requires six. This line sendMail(myemail,myemail,"Zalacznik","Tekst maila bla bla bla.", files) only has five.

Comment: @RodXavier, that's an insightful comment, and I think it deserves to be an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put the definition and call of `sendMail` alongside one another:

```
def sendMail(dir,     fromAddr, toAddr,      subject,                    text,  files):
          #  |        |         |            |                           |      !
    sendMail(myemail, myemail,  "Zalacznik", "Tekst maila bla bla bla.", files)
```

As Python interprets the arguments positionally it tells you  you're missing the last one, `files`, but I would say you're really missing the first one, `dir`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with sending emails, or attachments.

The signature of the `sendMail` function has as the first positional argument `dir` - although you don't use that anywhere in the function. However, when you call the function, you seem to have missed out that argument: the first parameter you send is an email, so is presumably intended to be `fromAddr`.

You probably just want to remove that argument from the definition.